# how to call long functions iteratively in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to iterate through a list of videos and convert them from .avi to .mp4 using a script, which takes about ~1 min for each file.

```sh
find . -name "*.avi" -type f | while read FILE; do
  HandbrakeCLI [flags] $FILE # execute 30 sec ~ 2 min function here
done
```

problem is, this seems to be only running on the first file, as though successive invocations are blocks.

How can I spawn asynchronous threads to handle each case?

---

This is a duplicate of that other issue which is trying to solve new processes of ssh, and the solution is based on arguments available to ssh.
I am asking for a way to spawn new bash threads in an iterator, maybe theres a duplicate ticket that can direct me that way?

Comment: Where do you use variable $FILE?

Comment: Just a side note. The loop is not required. You can use the `-exec` option of `find`: `find . -name "*.avi" -type f -exec HandbrakeCLI ... {} \;`

Comment: With ampersand `&` as last character in the commandline: `HandbrakeCLI &`. That starts a new thread for every command.

Comment: You can achieve that using [GNU Parallel][1].

For example, here is command to run 2 instances in parallel. `    find . -name "*.avi" -type f | parallel -j 2 "HandbrakeCLI {}"`. You may change `-j 2` parameter to change number of parallel instances.



  [1]: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Comment: @Cyrus sorry for being too concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your issue is the `HandbreakCLI` script is only called once, the root cause might be it behaves differently depending on whether the standard input is a terminal or not, or maybe does it drains its stdin. In such case, here is a way to overcome the issue from within `find`:

```
find . -type f -name  "*.avi" -exec sh -c 'FILE="$1" HandbrakeCLI &' sh {} \;
```

To trace what this command is running, you can modify it that way:

```
find . -type f -name  "*.avi" -exec sh -c 'set -x; FILE="$1" HandbrakeCLI &' sh {} \;
```

Comment: Not really. Trying out answering with a phone... Not easy.

Comment: Phone or not, the point is that this is doing the same as the while loop in the question.

Comment: @hek2mgl Well, to be honest, my first answer wasn't even doing the same as the OP loop as the script seems to pick its argument from a variable name, not a parameter. My first guess was the script was draining its standard input and preventing remaining occurrences to occur, but it looks I misunderstood the "are blocks" statement.

Comment: @hek2mgl Please do not edit my reply to change the script behavior. The OP script is passing the file to process as an environment variable, not as an argument.

Comment: Well, I've overlooked that particular point. I was mainly focussing on fixing syntax errors. What is the purpose of using backticks? What is the purpose of the `sh {} \;` at the end of the line?

Comment: @hek2mgl backticks were an issue with my phone keyboard, thanks for pointing it, fixed. The `sh {} \;` at the end of the script is a portable way to pass the filename as `{}` is only guaranteed to supported when alone in the line, per the POSIX standard.

Comment: Can you give a link to that POSIX document? I'm pointing to the additional `sh`, just to make that clear.

Comment: The "sh" is a convention, any string would work here although `sh` is less confusing that say `fubar`. It is passed as argument 0 to the shell. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#tag_20_117 , "sh -c" description and in particular "Set the value of special parameter 0".

Comment: Oh, I see your point, however, I strongly recommend to use `-` for that. (Or `--` if you want). That's far better to read. You see, at least I was confused by `sh`

Comment: Using `sh` is probably the most used convention. `-` would suggest it is a login shell, which it is not.

Comment: Ok, then it is probably me who is confusing others. :) The answer looks good now. +1 I would still recommend to not answer from a phone. Or learn typing! :P

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks, I'm learning by practice ;)

Comment: @jlliagre I am getting empty results from running the command you gave me and getting empty lines.

Comment: This command is not supposed to display anything by itself. If there are empty lines, either HandbrakeCLI is silent, or there are no `.avi` files to process. Answer updated to allow tracing the script execution.